# MYSQL Query of four tables

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck doing a query. I'd like to extract the 10 first records of one table considering the values of the other three tables. I'll try to explain what I want with an example:

**TABLES**

- `USERS`: username and date
- `POINTS`: id_user, points
- `COMMENTS`: id_user
- `WON`: id_user

**THE CRITERIA MUST BE**: The 10 users who have more points and, in case of equal values, with more comments published, less recent date date and didn't won. In that order.

```
SELECT id, username, date FROM users as us LIMIT 10 ORDER BY date DESC JOIN id_user, points FROM points as po WHERE us.id = po.id_user ORDER BY po.points DESC JOIN COUNT (id_user) FROM comments JOIN COUNT (id_user) FROM won;
```

I know that's wrong... :(

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please demonstrate your query and work done. Just asking for answers or code directly without attempting anything is not entertained by this site.

Comment: OK, so sorry. I'm new here :) I will post an idea and I hope anybody help me to solve that. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Users has an `id` field and a `created` datetime field, I think you're looking for something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Points ON Points.id_user = Users.id
LEFT JOIN Comments ON Comments.id_user = Users.id
LEFT JOIN Won ON Won.id_user = Users.id
GROUP BY Users.id
ORDER BY SUM(Points.points) DESC, COUNT(Comments.id) DESC, MAX(Users.created) DESC, COUNT(Won.id) DESC
```

Comment: I've tried and it works almost perfect. Just one change, I wanted order the users for created ASC because I want to give more chances to the oldest. So I put users.created ASC instead. But your help was really GREAT!. Thank you!!!